# How to use F# Union types with Servicestack JSON serialization?

Tags: json, f#, servicestack, c#-to-f#, servicestack-text

I guess it is too much I am asking from a framework. But just wondering if it is possible at all. Or what will be work around for this.

JSON.Net with new release started supporting F# union types. What is the work around for that, means if I am using servicestack.text, then how can I flatten union types to support serialization.

Here is code sample for both.

```
type Shape =
    | Rectangle of width : float * length : float
    | Circle of radius : float
    | Empty


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
//    printfn "%A" argv
    let shape1 = Rectangle(1.3, 10.0)

    let json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shape1) //JSON.net
    printfn "%A" json
    // {
    //   "Case": "Rectangle",
    //   "Fields": [
    //     1.3,
    //     10.0
    //   ]
    // }

    let shape2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Shape>(json) //JSON.Net
    printfn "%A" (shape2 = shape1) //true

    let sJson = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString shape1 //SS.Text
    printfn "%A" sJson

    let sShape2 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString sJson //SS.Text
    printfn "%A" (sShape2 = shape1) //false

    Console.Read() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Deserialization using servicestack is returning false. And also generated json string is quite complicated in compare to JSON.net.

How to achieve proper serialization for Union types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to give ServiceStack a custom serializer. It would like this, using a smaller Shape type for brevity:

```
open ServiceStack.Text

type Shape =
    | Circle of float
    | Empty

JsConfig<Shape>.SerializeFn 
    <- Func<_,_> (function
                  | Circle r -> sprintf "C %f" r
                  | Empty -> sprintf "E")

JsConfig<Shape>.DeSerializeFn 
    <- Func<_,_> (fun s ->    
                    match s.Split [| |] with
                    | [| "C"; r |] -> Circle (float r)
                    | [| "E" |] -> Empty)

let shapes = [| Circle 8.0 |]
let json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(shapes)
let shapes1 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Shape[]>(json)
let is_ok = shapes = shapes1
```

This code does not have proper exception-propagation in the deserializer: you'd want to handle the `match` not matching, and `float` might raise a `System.FormatException`.

Comment: It works. I have discussed the topic over groups. And I come to know about Fleece. It will be great if you can update the answer also with a sample of it, too. I guess that will solve the issue about serializing union type to JSON.